# Silverstripe Blog - DataExtension to Override FeaturedImage with Slideshow

Tags: silverstripe

I'm currently trying to replace the single "FeaturedImage" on the silverstripe blog with a slideshow. The original BlogPost.php looks like this:

```
class BlogPost extends Page {
    private static $has_one = array(
        'FeaturedImage' => 'Image',
    );
}
```

I've created the following file called BlogPostExtension.php and extended BlogPost with it in my main config.yml (BlogImage is a data object with a has_one image, meta information and the required relationships)

```
class BlogPostExtension extends DataExtension {
    private static $has_many = array(
        'Images' => 'BlogImage.Post',
    );
    public function FeaturedImage(){
        if($r = $this->owner->Images()->first()){
            if($r->Image()->ID>0){
                return $r->Image() ;
            }
        }
        return false ;
    }
}
```

I hoped the FeaturedImage function would degrade the old has_one relationship on BlogPost gracefully by instead serving up the first image in my slideshow. Unfortunately this didn't work. I also tried naming the FeaturedImage function "getFeaturedImage" with no success.

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve my goal? Do I need to remove the original has_one relationship in my DataExtension, and if so, how do I achieve this without modifying the core files?

Comment: Does your Image class have a has_one to BlogPost/Page/SiteTree? has_many needs a counterpart on the other side (has_one). Extend Image/File with such a relation or go with many_many I would say.

Comment: It does, but that also has nothing to do with the question I'm asking here at all. The only reason the relationship is even in the example is to show what I'm trying to achieve with the function below it.

Comment: I've added a little extra to the original post, hopefully this makes it clearer what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm not aware how to unset a relation on a extension. Out of curiosity what is the dot-notation on your has_many relation supposed to do? And why are this if's needed in your getter? Why can't you just straight `return  $this->owner->Images()->first();`

Comment: Firstly, the dot notation ensures silverstripe updates the correct id for the returning has_one relationship on the target object. For example, if I had a single object with multiple has_one => Page relationships.

Comment: Secondly, I can and have used $this->owner->Images()->first() elsewhere on the page. However, I want to be able to serve the cover image to existing templates and modules built using the FeaturedImage relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting approach you've taken, but you'd need to take a different approach to tackling this problem. Extensions extend a DataObject, not necessarily overwrite it.

I'd suggest setting `FeaturedImageID` to the first image ID in a `onBeforeWrite()` instead. You might also want to call `updateCMSFields()` and remove the `FeaturedImage` field for usability sake.

Something like this would be a good start to what you wanted:

```
class BlogPostExtension extends DataExtension {
    private static $has_many = array(
        'Images' => 'BlogImage.Post',
    );
    public function onBeforeWrite(){
        if($r = $this->owner->Images()->first()){
            if($r->Image()->ID > 0){
                $this->owner->FeaturedImageID = $r->Image()->ID ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is `BlogPost` `onBeforeWrite` does not get called when it's has many relationship gets edited. It's possible to add, reorder or delete images and not have `onBeforeWrite` called.

Comment: Cheers Flamer, I've already removed unwanted fields, etc, I just posted the code relating to my issue to keep it simple. As 3dgoo said, I will need to have the BlogImage call a write() on their BlogPost if I want to keep it updated when images are added/ordered, but aside from that it's a great solution. You've certainly set me on a better path, so thanks a lot for that.

Comment: Flamer, I've implemented your suggestion and it works well. The only downside is that the user must remember to save the page if they add, remove or re-order images to update the old has_one for FeaturedImage. I simply put a bold HTML message in a LiteralField above the BlogImages' grid to remind the user to do this. Thanks again.

Comment: A fair point, you could do a similar thing on the `BlogImage->onAfterWrite()` to trigger the `BlogPost` to save, then the user won't need to remember to save the `BlogPost` :)

Comment: I actually did try that but it didn't work and I didn't have the time to investigate why. I assumed grid field wasn't calling write() for one reason or another. I should probably look into that this weekend.